# cannot build assimp with minGw64

Tags: codeblocks, mingw-w64, assimp, cmake-gui

I used cmake and I was able to build a C::B project.
But Compiling the Assimp.cbp file raised a bunch of errors.
Is there someone experimented in compiling assimp with mingw64 under w10 for C::B to send me clues ?
Thks in advance. 
Here are the log errors :

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x8e): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::ValidateFlags(unsigned int) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const*, unsigned int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x14e): undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::create(char const*, Assimp::Logger::LogSeverity, unsigned int, Assimp::IOSystem*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::kill()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::GetErrorString() const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x2b9): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::Export(aiScene const*, char const*, char const*, unsigned int, Assimp::ExportProperties const*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x35c): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetErrorString() const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x426): undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::create(char const*, Assimp::Logger::LogSeverity, unsigned int, Assimp::IOSystem*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x435): undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::kill()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0xded): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const*, unsigned int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::create(char const*, Assimp::Logger::LogSeverity, unsigned int, Assimp::IOSystem*)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `Assimp::DefaultLogger::kill()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xb9): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::Importer()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xce): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::SetPropertyInteger(char const*, int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe2): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::Exporter()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x17b): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::IsExtensionSupported(char const*) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1b5): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::~Exporter()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1bd): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::~Importer()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x202): undefined reference to `aiGetCompileFlags'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x225): undefined reference to `aiGetVersionRevision'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x25e): undefined reference to `aiGetVersionMinor'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x265): undefined reference to `aiGetVersionMajor'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2ed): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount() const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2ff): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned long long) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x379): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount() const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x39b): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned long long) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x40c): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::GetExtensionList(aiString&) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x48b): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::ReadFile(char const*, unsigned int)'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x54d): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::~Exporter()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x555): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::~Importer()'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(WriteDumb.cpp.obj):WriteDumb.cpp:(.text+0x2ed3): undefined reference to `aiGetVersionRevision'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(WriteDumb.cpp.obj):WriteDumb.cpp:(.text+0x2ef6): undefined reference to `aiGetCompileFlags'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(WriteDumb.cpp.obj):WriteDumb.cpp:(.text+0x37a2): undefined reference to `aiGetVersionRevision'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(WriteDumb.cpp.obj):WriteDumb.cpp:(.text+0x37a9): undefined reference to `aiGetVersionMinor'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(WriteDumb.cpp.obj):WriteDumb.cpp:(.text+0x37b0): undefined reference to `aiGetVersionMajor'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Info.cpp.obj):Info.cpp:(.text+0x22d2): undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::GetMemoryRequirements(aiMemoryInfo&) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Info.cpp.obj):Info.cpp:(.text+0x2775): undefined reference to `aiGetMaterialString'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Info.cpp.obj):Info.cpp:(.text+0x288d): undefined reference to `aiGetMaterialString'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount() const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned long long) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned long long) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x7ac): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount() const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x7e4): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned long long) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x80f): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned long long) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0xabb): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount() const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0xaf4): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned long long) const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x106c): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatCount() const'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir/objects.a(Export.cpp.obj):Export.cpp:(.text+0x10a4): undefined reference to `Assimp::Exporter::GetExportFormatDescription(unsigned long long) const'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [tools\assimp_cmd\CMakeFiles\assimp_cmd.dir\build.make:177: tools/assimp_cmd/assimp.exe] Error 1
Le processus s'est terminé avec le code d'état 2 (8 minute(s), 52 seconde(s))
50 erreur(s), 113 avertissement(s) (8 minute(s), 52 seconde(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I build it under MSYS2 with MinGW-w64:

```
tar xfz v5.0.0.tar.gz
cd assimp-5.0.0
# fix missing strcasecmp/strncasecmp in code/StringComparison.h (version >= 4.0.0)
mv code/StringComparison.h code/StringComparison.h.bak &&
sed -e "s/strcasecmp/stricmp/g; s/strncasecmp/strnicmp/g" code/StringComparison.h.bak > code/StringComparison.h
mkdir -p build_static build_shared &&
 cd build_static &&
 cmake.exe -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_HEADERCHECK:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_OPT_BUILD_PACKAGES:BOOL=OFF -DSYSTEM_IRRXML:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_SAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF .. &&
 cd .. &&
 cd build_shared &&
 cmake.exe -G"MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON -DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_HEADERCHECK:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_OPT_BUILD_PACKAGES:BOOL=OFF -DSYSTEM_IRRXML:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_SAMPLES:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF -DASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF .. &&
 cd .. &&
 # fix missing ../../revision.h
 cp -f build_shared/revision.h . &&
 make -Cbuild_static install/strip &&
 make -Cbuild_shared install/strip &&
 echo Success
```

Replace `/usr/local` with the destination folder that you need.

I was not successful building it with `-DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS:BOOL=ON` though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know assimp library, but if you use msys2, you can install the complete package (dynamic and static library and all the header files) with the command:
`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-assimp`.

Comment: thks for your answer. Error: impossible to find the target :  mingw-64-x86_64-assimp.

Comment: I think it should be `mingw-w64-x86_64-assimp`, but I havn't tested.

Comment: I ran your command in a msys2 prompt. This worked with no errors . This means that the lib was correctly build ? Where it is now ? It was confusing to me that MSys2 is an alternate to cmake.

Comment: If you would like to know what has been installed as a part of a specific package use the following command: 
`pacman -Ql mingw-w64_x86_64-assimp` .
This command lists the content of the package and where it's located (inside the `C:/msys64/mingw64` directory)

Comment: I think **pacman** (package manager) installs the pre-compiled content of the package, and that isn't compiled on your machine.

Comment: Thk you very much. The option -Ql gave me a list of header files and libassimp.dll but no .lib files apparently

Comment: it seems that adding a path to the header files and the link to the static lib libassimp.dll.a makes it work. Am i correct ?

Comment: The *.lib files are generated by visual studio. The library files generated by GCC have *.a extension. You need to add **libassimp.dll.a** to your project linker options, add path to header files, and put the dll file both in your executable directory and in codeblocks project directory (where is the cbp file).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the tools are currently not working with this compiler. I need to check that.

Comment: Which tools? Which compiler? Why you?

Comment: The tools provided by the library - like the viewer. And I wrote most of them, so me :-).

Comment: So you (largely) wrote assimp? In that case please accept my humble expression of respect.

Comment: Not all the stuff, I am the project lead. And not to worry. The mingw build for the tools is broken, so please disable it.