# Building Assimp with MSYS

Tags: c++, msys2, building, assimp

Hello i tried to build Assimp.
I'm using gcc (10.2.0) and MSYS2.

It's possible to download Assimp package from MSYS package repository but i prefer to build  Assimp from scratch.

while   building Assimp a error message appeared:

```
/c/Users/MY_NAME/Downloads/assimp-5.0.1/assimp-5.0.1/include/assimp/StringComparison.h: In function ‘int Assimp::ASSIMP_stricmp(const char*, const char*)’:
/c/Users/MY_NAME/Downloads/assimp-5.0.1/assimp-5.0.1/include/assimp/StringComparison.h:146:14: error: ‘::strcasecmp’ has not been declared; did you mean ‘strncmp’?
```

I executed cmake with following commands:

```
cmake  CMakelists.txt  -S ./  -B ./BUILD_ASSIMP
```

then i executed "make"

Could you help me?

Comment: If you show what is on line 7 of zlib1.rc then people will have more idea about what is going wrong with your build.

Comment: You're using MSYS2, not MSYS, right? They are different.

Comment: Why do you want to build it yourself? MSYS2 lets you download a prebuilt one.

Comment: I'm using MSYS2

Comment: Here is the  sentence (zlib1.rc:7):      

VS_VERSION_INFO  VERSIONINFO MOVEABLE IMPURE LOADONCALL DISCARDABLE

Comment: This is line 7 of zlib1.rc

Comment: Edited your question to say MSYS2 instead of MSYS. Please add any new information to the question by editing it, instead of posting it in the comments. And again, why do you want to build assimp yourself when you can download a prebuilt one from MSYS2?

Comment: Can you explain step by step what exactly you did? What commands are you using to build?

Comment: Based on the file paths it looks like you are a trying to compile the version of zlib packaged with assimp.  There are precompiled zlib packages for MSYS2, so maybe you can just configure the assimp build system to use the system zlib instead of compiling its own.

Comment: How did you install your compiler inside MSYS2? You did `pacman -S gcc`, didn't you? I'm not sure if it's the source of the problem, but that's definitely not the version of GCC you need (it builds apps with cygwin-based POSIX emulation, which is only good for porting non-portable programs originally written for Linux to Windows). Get rid of this one, and install the proper GCC using `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`.

Comment: In general, always use packages prefixed with `mingw-w64-x86_64-` for libraries, compilers, and various tools. Only use unprefixed package for command line utilities such as `grep`, `make`, etc.
Also you need to restart MSYS2 using `mingw64.exe`, otherwise this compiler won't be included in the `PATH`; if done correctly you should see `MINGW64` written in pink in the command prompt, instead of `MSYS`.

Comment: This looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59032997/2752075 , someone got the same error as you. (Weirdly, I don't get this error, but I'm running somewhat modified MSYS2.) Also make sure you uninstall all other GCC versions that you might have on your system, including that unprefixed `gcc` package.

Comment: Also, would appreciate comments if you try my advice and it works or doesn't work. So far I've only replied because I checked your question for silent edits.

Comment: i looked  this link you gave were someone else had a similar issue like me but i don't found any solutions.

Comment: Please begin your comments with `@username`, otherwise I don't get notifications. You always get notifications because the comments are under your question.

Comment: What do you mean by no solutions? There are specific commands for you to try. What happens if you use them?

Answer (score 0):

the function call, which is creating your issue is an extension of the Posix-standard. e have our own implementation for this when the function is not supported by your compiler. Unfortunately, the check if the call exists was not correct for your environment.

I just prepared an update on our current master to work around[Asset-Importer-Lib@github](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) this issue. It would be great if you can use the latest master. The issue will be closed in the next release.